# xmlrpc ouput not woking as desired

Tags: php, arrays, xml, codeigniter

i am new to codeigniter and getting error while using XMLRPC for sending a specific xml call to a remote server.  I have tried a lot of array examples but not getting the exact out put from my server.

XML Format we required as output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
 <OTA_HotelAvailRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
  <POS>
   <Source>
    <RequestorID MessagePassword= "****" ID= "****" Type="CHM"/>
   </Source>
  </POS>
 <AvailRequestSegments>
  <AvailRequestSegment>
   <HotelSearchCriteria>
    <Criterion>
     <HotelRef HotelCode="00008382"/>
     <StayDateRange Start="2014-12-10" End="2014-12-29">
   </StayDateRange>
  </Criterion>
 </HotelSearchCriteria>
 </AvailRequestSegment>
</AvailRequestSegments>
</OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
```

Already tried structures of array

1. $request = array (
            array('RequestorID'=>array('MessagePassword'=>'testDataCorp','ID'=>'datacorp','Type'=>'CHM')),
                      array('HotelRef'=>array('HotelCode'=>'00008164')),
                           array('StayDateRange'=>array('Start'=>'2016-04-01','End'=>'2016-04-12')));

   2.$request = array('Source' => array( 'RequestorID'=>array( 'MessagePassword'=> 'testDataCorp', 'ID'=>'datacorp','Type'=>'CHM')                                      ),array('HotelRef'=>array('HotelCode'=>'00008164')),
                    array('StayDateRange'=>array('StayDateRange (Start)'=>'2016-04-01','StayDateRange (End)'=>'2016-04-12'))
   );
2. array(
       array('MessagePassword', 'testDataCorp'),
       array('ID', 'datacorp'),
        array('Type', 'CHM'),
         array('HotelCode', '00008164'),
          array('StayDateRange(Start)', '2016-04-01'),
          array('StayDateRange(End)', '2016-04-12')
   );

kindly help me so that i can get the exact ouput.
Thanks & Regards
Sandeep Goel